# Unable to turn VBA string into Excel cell formula

Tags: excel, vba, formula

Tring to make the following code work. For some reason returns a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

The code is the following:

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
Dim lastFlight, lastMis, logBook, studentCode As String
Dim i, j, k, numRows As Integer
Dim wb0 As Workbook
Dim studentSheet As Worksheet

Set wb0 = ActiveWorkbook

Set studentSheet = wb0.Worksheets("STUDENTS")

numRows = studentSheet.Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

studentCode = studentSheet.Cells(8, 2).Value

lastFlight = "=MAIOR('\\server\# FLTLOG_EXPORT\[" & studentCode & ".xlsx]Status'!$A$3:$A$219;1)"
lastMis = "=PROC(2;1/(1-É.CÉL.VAZIA('\\server\# FLTLOG_EXPORT\[" & studentCode & ".xlsx]Status'!$C$3:$C$230));'\\server\# FLTLOG_EXPORT\[" & studentCode & ".xlsx]Status'!$C$3:$C$230)"
logBook = "'\\server\# FLTLOG_EXPORT\[" & studentCode & ".xlsx]Desvios'!$Q$15"

ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 4).Formula = lastFlight

End Sub
```

The formulas are in Portuguese and MAIOR is LARGE, PROC is LOOKUP. The code stops in the:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 4).Formula = lastFlight
```

Please help. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please note that if you declare

```
Dim i, j, k, numRows As Integer
```

only `numRows` is `Integer` but all the others are of type `Variant`. It is exactly the same as writing:

```
Dim i As Variant, j As Variant, k As Variant, numRows As Integer
```

In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable. Also Excel has more rows than fit into an `Integer`, so you must use `Long` instead. [Also there is no benefit in using `Integer` in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520) so I recommend always to use `Long` instead:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, numRows As Long
```

Same applies to your other multiple variables declared in one line.

---

Another recommendation is to avoid `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` if possible.
Note that `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has focus / is on top. This can change easily by a single user click. What you probably meant to use is `ThisWorkbook` which is the workbook this VBA code is written in (and it never changes).

Instead of `ActiveSheet.Cells` specify the worbkook and worksheet explicitly for your `Cells` object. Like `studentSheet.Cells` or something similar.

---

#### To your actual issue

Note that the file `studentCode & ".xlsx` needs to be open if you want to use it in a formula.

Make sure you open it with

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\server\# FLTLOG_EXPORT\" & studentCode & ".xlsx"
```

Then you can use it in your formula without the path:

```
lastFlight = "=MAIOR('[" & studentCode & ".xlsx]Status'!$A$3:$A$219;1)"
```